# Creating a directory in CMake

Tags: cmake

In CMake, I want to create a directory if it doesn't already exist. How can I do this?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

When do you want to create the directory?

#### At build system generation

To create a directory when CMake generates the build system,

```
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${directory})
```

#### At build time

In the `add_custom_command()` command (which adds a custom build rule to the generated build system), and the `add_custom_target()` command (which adds a target with no output so it will always be built), you specify the commands to execute at build time. Create a directory by executing the command `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory`. For example:

```
add_custom_target(build-time-make-directory ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${directory})
```

#### At install time

To create a directory at install time,

```
install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION ${directory})
```

Comment: Succint and quick. Hits the target right away! Thanks.

Comment: cmake -E is not a recognized flag.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool

Answer (score 30):

To create a directory at install time,

```
install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION ${directory})
```

These will *both* run at configure time:

```
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${directory})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${directory})
```

To create during the build, use a custom target:

```
add_custom_target(mytargetname ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${directory})
```

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Chin Huang's reply, you can also do this at build time with `add_custom_command`:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${target_name} PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${directory})
```

You can also change the moment, when your directory is created with `PRE_BUILD` | `PRE_LINK` | `POST_BUILD` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to create a directory at **install time**, it was necessary to specify the `COMPONENT_NAME`:

```
install (DIRECTORY 
    COMPONENT  ${COMPONENT_NAME}
    DESTINATION "/Logs" 
)
```

I hope this can be useful for someone