# Can Cmake generate a single makefile that supports both debug and release

Tags: c++, c, cmake

It seems like we need to create separate folder for each build type (debug/release), run cmake on each, and generate separate makefile for debug/release configuration. Is it possible to create one single makefile using cmake that supports both debug/release configuration at the same time and when we actually run "make" that will create separate folders for the intermediate and final products (like the dlls, exe).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be achieved using a single set of build scripts.  However, what you can do is have two sub-directories of your working area:

```
build/
build/debug
build/release
```

Then do:

```
$ cd build
$
$ cd build/debug
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../..
$ make
$
$ cd ../release
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../..
$ make
```

If necessary, you can add another build script in the `build` directory as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd debug   && make && cd ..
cd release && make && cd ..
```

Comment: what about the visual studio sln file, does it also generate debug only or release only configuration or does it support both in the same .sln file?

Comment: @user243655: It seems to generate multiple configurations: `Debug`, `Release`, `MinSizeRel` and `RelWithDebInfo`.

Answer (score 11):

This can be achieved using the `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET` command. For example, if you want to add both debug and release targets in your makefile, add the following to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Creating the executable in the debug mode.")

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Creating the executable in the release mode.")
```

Then, after configuring with cmake, you can run `make debug` to make the debug target and run `make release` to make the release target in the same directory.

Comment: What if I don't want them in the same directory (but separate subdirectories)?

Comment: @def: `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is defined and cached based on the directory that you run the `cmake` command. However, after building we can install it to another location. Also you can copy the build executable to separate directories:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by [@a.sam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412977/6197439), I can now provide a self-contained working example; you can thank me later `:)`

Essentially, here I invent a `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` that does not exist in `cmake` (`cmake` does not know about it), - here called `SingleBuildDir` - and use it to distinguish between creating a top-level Makefile, or debug/release Makefiles.

Just save the below file as `CMakeLists.txt` somewhere:

```cmake
# instead of calling the following in build subdir, as we used to:
# cmake.exe  ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "MSYS Makefiles"
# now we want to try something like:
# cmake.exe  ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=SingleBuildDir -G "MSYS Makefiles"
# ... and then have `make debug` build in build/Debug, and `make release` build in build/Release
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083427/can-cmake-generate-a-single-makefile-that-supports-both-debug-and-release

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968979/how-to-make-colorized-message-with-cmake
#if(NOT WIN32) # well, get rid of this, as it detects MINGW bash as WIN32 too
  string(ASCII 27 Esc)
  set(ColourReset "${Esc}[m")
  set(ColourBold  "${Esc}[1m")
  set(Red         "${Esc}[31m")
  set(Green       "${Esc}[32m")
  set(Yellow      "${Esc}[33m")
  set(Blue        "${Esc}[34m")
  set(Magenta     "${Esc}[35m")
  set(Cyan        "${Esc}[36m")
  set(White       "${Esc}[37m")
  set(BoldRed     "${Esc}[1;31m")
  set(BoldGreen   "${Esc}[1;32m")
  set(BoldYellow  "${Esc}[1;33m")
  set(BoldBlue    "${Esc}[1;34m")
  set(BoldMagenta "${Esc}[1;35m")
  set(BoldCyan    "${Esc}[1;36m")
  set(BoldWhite   "${Esc}[1;37m")
#endif()

if (NOT(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c" AND NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c"))
  message("${Cyan}Creating ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c${ColourReset}")
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637539/how-to-split-strings-across-multiple-lines-in-cmake
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69574555/cmake-filegenerate-output-output-file-how-to-write-content-on-multiple
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674998/cmakelists-create-string-with-new-lines
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193171/cmake-how-to-create-a-file-with-make-command # example for file(write
  FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c
    "#include <stdio.h>\n"
    "\n"
    "int main() {\n"
    "  printf(\"Hello from test_cmake_singlebuilddir main.exe!\\n\");\n"
    "  return 0;\n"
    "}\n"
  )
endif() # NOT(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c"

# NOTE: apparently, project command MUST be first;
# else the `make debug` might fail with "Error: could not find CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME in Cache"
# (via [Error could not find CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME in Cache · Issue #90 · facebookresearch/habitat-sim · GitHub](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-sim/issues/90))
project(test_singlebuilddir C)


message("${Cyan}Current CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE mode: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}${ColourReset}")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "SingleBuildDir")
  message("${Yellow}Create subdirectories in build (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}): ./Debug, ./Release${ColourReset}")
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702115/creating-a-directory-in-cmake
  # "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR is defined and cached based on the directory that you run the cmake command" SO:10083427
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug)
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release)

  message("${Yellow}Creating top-level makefile${ColourReset}") # SO:10083427

  message("${Yellow}Initialize Debug directory${ColourReset}")
  execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug
  )
  message("${Yellow}Add debug build target${ColourReset}")
  ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target all
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug
    COMMENT "Creating the executable in the debug mode."
  )

  message("${Yellow}Initialize Release directory${ColourReset}")
  execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release
  )
  message("${Yellow}Add release build target${ColourReset}")
  ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target all
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release
    COMMENT "Creating the executable in the release mode."
  )

  # if we ended up here, exit early; no real cmake command for that:
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192628/can-i-stop-cmake-processing-without-an-error
  # ... but try return?:
  return() # seems to work!
endif() # CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "SingleBuildDir"


message("${Cyan}Proceed with rest of CMakeLists.txt - actual project setup ...${ColourReset}")


#project(test_singlebuilddir C) # if here, "Error: could not find CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME in Cache"
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
message("${Cyan}PROJECT_NAME is '${PROJECT_NAME}'${ColourReset}")

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources
    main.c
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})
```

And command line output is as follows; note I have to propagate -g "MSYS2 Makefiles" since I'm on Windows MSYS2 bash shell:

```
$ # in the directory where CMakeLists.txt is:
$ mkdir build
$ cd build

$ # check state of this and parent folder
$ ls -la ..
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None    0 Oct  6 19:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None    0 Oct  6 17:40 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None    0 Oct  6 19:14 build/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None 4.8K Oct  6 18:59 CMakeLists.txt

$ ls -la .
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None 0 Oct  6 19:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None 0 Oct  6 19:14 ../

$ # run cmake

$ cmake  ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=SingleBuildDir -G "MSYS Makefiles"
Creating C:/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/main.c
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
Current CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE mode: SingleBuildDir
Create subdirectories in build (C:/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build): ./Debug, ./Release
Creating top-level makefile
Initialize Debug directory
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
Current CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE mode: Debug
Proceed with rest of CMakeLists.txt - actual project setup ...
PROJECT_NAME is 'test_singlebuilddir'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug
Add debug build target
Initialize Release directory
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
Current CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE mode: Release
Proceed with rest of CMakeLists.txt - actual project setup ...
PROJECT_NAME is 'test_singlebuilddir'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release
Add release build target
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build

$ # try it out

$ make debug
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
Scanning dependencies of target debug
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
[100%] Creating the executable in the debug mode.
make[4]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
make[5]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
make[6]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
Scanning dependencies of target test_singlebuilddir
make[6]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
make[6]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_singlebuilddir.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable test_singlebuilddir.exe
make[6]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
[100%] Built target test_singlebuilddir
make[5]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Debug'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
[100%] Built target debug
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'

$ make release
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
Scanning dependencies of target release
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
[100%] Creating the executable in the release mode.
make[4]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
make[5]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
make[6]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
Scanning dependencies of target test_singlebuilddir
make[6]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
make[6]: Entering directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_singlebuilddir.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable test_singlebuilddir.exe
make[6]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
[100%] Built target test_singlebuilddir
make[5]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build/Release'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
[100%] Built target release
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/test_cmake_singlebuilddir/build'

$ # check where the produced executables are located:

$ find . -name '*.exe'
./CMakeFiles/3.14.3/CompilerIdC/a.exe
./Debug/CMakeFiles/3.14.3/CompilerIdC/a.exe
./Debug/test_singlebuilddir.exe
./Release/CMakeFiles/3.14.3/CompilerIdC/a.exe
./Release/test_singlebuilddir.exe
```

There we go - exactly what I've wanted for quite some time!