# Colorized output for cmake but only to screen, not to file

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to have colorized output in `cmake` for messages,  [(e.g. like here is written)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968979/how-to-get-colorized-output-with-cmake) , but only when output is not redirected to a file (and using only cmake's possibilities)? Because using that method, messages in the file are colorized too (escape sequences printed).

I'd like to be able to force and compiler flags like `-fdiagnostics-color` for gcc or `-fcolor-diagnostics` for clang. On some platforms compiler doesn't colorize output without these flags. I think it's impossible to do this correctly. The flags are cached and every time, when `make` is started, it uses the same value as was configured when `cmake` was started for first time. I don't know how to change flags in dependence if output is redirected to screen or to file, but  if it is possible, I'd like to know.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a way to have colorized output in cmake for messages but only when output is not redirected to a file
>   I don't know.

For the other question, with recent enough versions of clang or gcc I get automatic coloring depending on whether the output is a terminal. I'm sorry if you can't upgrade your compiler right now, but I'm sure you'll do it eventually :)