# How Cmake colorizes output?

Tags: bash, cmake, kdevelop

Following the advice given to question
[How to get colorized output with cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968979/how-to-get-colorized-output-with-cmake) I attempted to colorize the output. Two strange experiences

1./ When using bold coloring, an unneeded ';' is inserted at the place where the color is changed. (KDevelop 4.7.3; Ubuntu 16.04; the code is simply copy/paste-ed from the reference)

2./ When I run CMake directly, from a command line  window, the coloring works OK (apart from the obsolete ';'). However, when running from KDevelop, using 'Build', my colorization just prints  the escape sequences, rather than coloring the output. At the same time, CMake colorization works. What is the difference?

Comment: It seems to be a problem of kdevelop. Which version? Which operating system? Can you be a little bit more precise about point 1? (Maybe some cmake code and a screenshot would help)

Comment: Update KDevelop and/or file a bug.

Comment: The KDevelop terminal emulator probably doesn't handle escape sequences correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDevelop does not support ANSI escape sequences (color codes) in its output view.

Up to KDevelop 4.x, KDevelop showed the escape sequences in the output view, starting with 5.0 we filter them out.

Also see: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=321939