# determine whether cmake is executing from terminal or gui

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

In `CMakeLists.txt`, is there a way to know whether the file was executed from a terminal or via a gui (of some form, e.g. `ccmake` or `cmake-gui`)?  `CMAKE_COMMAND` and `CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND` are both populated regardless of whether I am running `cmake` or `ccmake`.

I was searching through the [variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) and these two seemed the most promising.  I have become enamored with [colorizing cmake output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18968979/3814202), the many wonderful answers there have their drawbacks.  Namely, I can either get:

1. It works as expected in a terminal, but there are escape sequences in `ccmake`.
2. It works as expected in a terminal, but the `ccmake` terminal is *overwritten* by colorized output (LOL).

Just curious if there is a way to determine this in the `CMakeLists.txt`.  There were variables for script mode (`-P`) that seemed potentially helpful, but I think I would first need to know which executable (`cmake` or `ccmake`) called my `CMakeLists.txt` in the first place.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to distinguish cmake from cmake-gui within CMake. What's your usecase? It should behave the samea anyhow, everything else would be a surprise.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it is possible to distinguish either.  The use case is quite minute, and I honestly can't think of another reason why anybody would even want this.  My library is able to compile its external dependencies for the user, but **not** able to perform final steps of installation (adding files to locations that need elevated permissions).  I added colorized output to draw attention to this (because my application cannot run without the user performing the extra steps).  But the GUIs don't like my colorized output x0

Comment: Your terminal should handle the colorized output. Probably you are adding it directly to the output, which is the real cause for your problem.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the problem. I suppose I'll just stick with the warning variant of message, that's what it's there for after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to distinguish whether the code was invoked from CMake or from CMake-gui. The code should behave in the same way, everything else would be a surprise for the user.

You could try to detect whether an instance of CMake-gui is running, but this is error-prone and is not justified for real use cases.

Comment: Too bad. I just might have to look into the source code and submit a patch assuming the solution would be unintrusive. I've seen in Python the ability to detect whether output is going to a terminal or pipe to a file, and if file they removed the coloring. Regardless, thanks for weighing in :)

Comment: @svenevs, I came here because I stumbled in exatly the same issue as you: the colorized output does not work when running `ccmake`. Did you find a solution for that? Or, alternatively, did you find how to make `ccmake` interpret the colorized sequences correctly? Thanks a lot for your kind help in advance!! (BTW: +1 for the question!)

Comment: Is CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE of any help? See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE.html