# How-to have colored console output if using CMake script mode with the execute_process command?

Tags: windows, cmd, build, cmake, msbuild

I'm currently rewriting a CMake-based build system and got rid of all platform-dependent script files (e.g. Windows Batch).

There is only one `.cmd` file that calls CMake as follows (a bit more complex, but the idea is that an user never has to invoke `cmake` directly).

```
cmake -P foo.cmake
```

In the `foo.cmake` script the actual configure (or `--build`) call with `cmake` is executed, e.g.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

execute_process(
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  ENCODING AUTO
  )
```

Now, when `cmake -P foo.cmake` is invoked, the output written to the console is **not** colored. If `cmake --build .` is executed in a terminal, the output is colored.

I'm using Microsoft Windows v6.1.7601, CMake 3.17.2 and MSBuild 15.5.180.51428.

1. How-to have colored console output if using CMake script mode with the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command?
2. If it is not possible with `execute_process`: Does any alternative exist?

Related:

- [How to get colorized output with cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968979/how-to-get-colorized-output-with-cmake)
- http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/quot-cmake-build-quot-and-colors-td7584342.html
- http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Coloured-output-for-cmake-on-windows-td4279033.html
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/478

Comment: Your question really has nothing whatsoever to do with [[tag:batch-file]], so you really shouldn't be using its tag. All you have inside your `.cmd` file is a command, (to run an executable file with an argument), and that command could easily be run from any command line interface, and with a whole host of consoles/terminals. Now as you're clearly using Windows, specify the terminal/console in your question body and also replace your [[tag:batch-file]] tag with [[tag:cmd]], [[tag:powershell]] or whatever matches the console/terminal your question relates to. Thank you.

Comment: @Compo You're right, I've used the wrong tag. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give Visual Studio Code and the [Output Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer) extension a try