# Can I Stop CMake Processing without an Error

Tags: cmake

I need to be able to stop CMake processing from within a CMake function or macro.  I don't want to stop processing just the current file, but **stop ALL CMake processing**.  Right now, I am using `message(FATAL_ERROR "Foo")`.  The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/message.html) for `message` states it does exactly what I *need*:

> CMake Error, stop processing and generation

However, I would *like* to be able to do this without generating an error.  I really don't need a message either.  I just want to completely exit.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If your CMakeLists.txt hierarchy is fairly shallow, you can call [`return()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/return.html) once or twice (depending on if you called `add_subdirectory()` or if you're in a macro/function) to return to the calling file or function and exit CMake processing.

If your project hierarchy is more complex, and you want to exit your CMakes from an arbitrary location, there is no native CMake command to support that. However, you could roll your own (admittedly, a bit scary) solution to terminate `cmake`:

```
function(exit_cmake)
  if(UNIX)
    set(KILL_COMMAND "killall")
    execute_process(COMMAND ${KILL_COMMAND} -9 cmake
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    )
  else()
    set(KILL_COMMAND "taskkill")
    execute_process(COMMAND ${KILL_COMMAND} /IM cmake.exe /F
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    )
  endif()
endfunction()
```

If you include this in your top-level CMake file, you can call this from anywhere in your CMakes to exit silently.

**WARNING**: This will terminate *ALL* currently running CMake processes, not just your current process. Because you are forcing the process the terminate, your CMake files/cache may be left in a weird state.

Comment: "Exiting from an arbitrary location" is what I want.  The referenced answer still seems to generate output (at least a stack trace).  What I am looking for is a **completely silent** way of terminating CMake processing.

Comment: You are right, I tested the `message()` override and it doesn't work as I hoped. I'll redact that from my answer.

Comment: @DiB I edited my answer with a solution that appears to work on my machine (Windows 10), and should also work on Linux. Although it's not the best solution, you can try it and see if it works for your case.

Comment: That is a creative approach.  I am worried that it would have unintended consequences in a production environment that could be running multiple copies of CMake at the same time.  Like you said: "a bit scary".