# CMakeLists: Create string with new lines

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

I had a problem trying to print a string with new lines in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Expected output:

```
{file}:{line}:{column}
  Message: {message}
    Check: CWE-{cwe}
     Type: {severity} -> {id}
     Line: {line}:{column}
    Stack: {callstack}
{code}
```

If I try to put the new line scape symbol (`\n`), then it returns an error:

```
set(CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "{file}:{line}:{column}\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "  Message: {message}\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "    Check: CWE-{cwe}\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "     Type: {severity} -> {id}\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "     Line: {line}:{column}\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "    Stack: {callstack}\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "{code}\n")
```

Implementation:

```
add_custom_command(
        COMMENT "Scanning: CPP Check\n"
        TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND cppcheck
        "--template=${CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE}"
        VERBATIM
)
```

Error:

```
/home/wolf/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/211.7142.21/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/wolf/workspace/projects/bose-connect-app-linux/src/cmake-build-debug --target clean -- -j 6
CMakeFiles/bose-connect-app-linux.dir/build.make:157: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:113: CMakeFiles/bose-connect-app-linux.dir/clean] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:109: clean] Error 2
```

Comment: Hi, @fabian. It is definitely not relevant what I use this variable for. The purpose can be any, but if you pay attention I am using `CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE`. **The problem is clear, a text is assigned to a variable and that text has new lines, which are not displayed.** In my specific case I am using this text as a parameter in a Linux command. Did you test the code on your computer locally? BTW, thanks for your comment, I added where I am using this variable to clarify better.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many possibilities and I did not get any solution. I discovered that if the backslash `\` is escaped, then it recognizes the new line (`\\n`):

```
set(CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "{file}:{line}:{column}\\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "  Message: {message}\\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "    Check: CWE-{cwe}\\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "     Type: {severity} -> {id}\\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "     Line: {line}:{column}\\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "    Stack: {callstack}\\n")
string(APPEND CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE "{code}\\n")
```

Also, it works for any string in the `CMakeLists.txt` for example in a comment (`COMMENT "Scanning: CPP Check\n\n"`):

```
add_custom_command(
        COMMENT "Scanning: CPP Check\n\n"
        TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND cppcheck
        "--language=c"
        "--std=c11"
        "--platform=unix64"
        "--template=${CPPCHECK_TEMPLATE}"
        "--project=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json"
        "--error-exitcode=1"
        VERBATIM)
```

The output without the new lines in the comment:

```
Scanning: CPP Check
Checking /home/wolf/workspace/projects/bose-connect-app-linux/src/main.c ...
```

The output with the new lines in the comment:

```
Scanning: CPP Check

Checking /home/wolf/workspace/projects/bose-connect-app-linux/src/main.c ...
```