# CMake file(GENERATE OUTPUT <output-file> [...]) how to write CONTENT on multiple lines

Tags: cmake

Given the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test_package_lib)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME})
foo(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

where `foo` function is defined like this:

```
function(foo TARGET)
    set(FILENAME_RELEASE $<TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME:${TARGET}>.dll)

    # This works!
    file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/text.log CONTENT "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${TARGET}> ${FILENAME_RELEASE}")

    # This produces CMake errors
    file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/text.log CONTENT [==[
$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${TARGET}>
${FILENAME_RELEASE}]==])

endfunction()
```

The first `file(GENERATE...)` produces the output: `test_package_lib.dll test_package_lib.dll`

The second `file(GENERATE...)` call results into the following error:

```
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${TARGET}>

  Expression syntax not recognized.
```

How is it possible to write the `CONTENT` on multiple lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside [bracket-argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) variable's **dereference** is **not performed**. This is why you get line `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${TARGET}>` in the error message: it has unexpanded `${TARGET}`.

Instead bracket-argument use "normal" quoted argument splitted over several lines:

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/text.log CONTENT
  "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${TARGET}>
${FILENAME_RELEASE}"
)
```