# During build, how to create a directory for a file which is generated by some COMMAND?

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a custom command in CMake to convert a file to binary format at build time. However, the tool I'm using requires directory for a file to be pre-existed; it doesn't create a directory automatically.

Currently my CMake macro looks like this:

```
MACRO(ConvertToBinary _name)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${_name}.bin
        COMMAND ${EXE_DIR}/toBinary -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_name} -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${_name}.bin
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_name}
    )
ENDMACRO(ConvertToBinary)
```

This macro doesn't work for `_name` parameter equal, e.g., to "test/sample.txt", because the tool is run with `test/` folder under `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` being not existed.

How to create the directory before the tool, generating the file, is run?

---

I have tried to overcome the problem by pre-creating the file (and directory) with the help of CMake. So the tool will be run with the directory created, and can override the output file. I have tried the following:

```
MACRO(ConvertToBinary _name)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${_name}.bin
        FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${_name}.bin "Dummy")
        COMMAND ${EXE_DIR}/toBinary -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_name} -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${_name}.bin
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_name}
    )
ENDMACRO(ConvertToBinary)
```

But it did not work. I can't find information on how to create file at build time with CMake, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use CMake's [command line tool mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode).

Comment: @Florian: Referenced question describes how to create a directory, but doesn't describe **how to extract directory component from the file**. (Well, I know it is simple with [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/get_filename_component.html)). But as tools not creating directory for output file are quite common, it would be usefull to have a question/answer(s) about complete resolution for that problem. (Another approach could be adding corresponded answer for the related question, but without changing that question itself it seems to be not efficient).

Comment: @Cyril: I have slightly rearrange your question post for separate your **main problem** (creating a directory for the file) from your attempt for overcome that (creating the file itself). Feel free to more improve the question, so future readers will find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CMake you may extract directory component of the file and create this directory.

Below code can be used for a tool, which generates a file but doesn't create directory for it.

```
# Assume some tool generates file '${file}', but don't create directory for it.
#
# Extract directory component for a file
get_filename_component(_dir ${file} DIRECTORY)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${file}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${_dir} # Create output directory
    COMMAND <tool-which-generates-file> ... ${file}
)
```

See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702115/creating-a-directory-in-cmake) about ways for create a directory in CMake.